# Background mining + monero-wallet-cli + pool?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mining, mining-pools, linux

Is it possible to launch the monero-wallet-cli for mining with the experimental background-mining feature on?

And would it be possible to connect to a pool for that?

Basically I just want my CPU cores to mine whenever my computer goes idle or is underutilizing the cores. As far as I can see the "monerod" miner did not allow for "background mining if idle".

I'm using Arch Linux btw.

Comment: Please, how long does it it take for monero background mining to pay mined coins into wallet

Comment: It depends on your hash rate. On average, a number of minutes equal to twice the network hash rate divided by your hash rate. But it will likely vary widely from that average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background mining system does not use a pool. It will instruct monerod to mine, and monerod does not use a pool.

Background mining has existed in monerod for a few years. It was just hard to find, and so not used much. This is the reason why it was exposed in the wallet too.

To enable background mining in monerod, you pass extra arguments to `start_mining`:

```
help start_mining
Command usage: 
  start_mining <addr> [<threads>|auto] [do_background_mining] [ignore_battery]

Command description: 
  Start mining for specified address. Defaults to 1 thread and no background mining. Use "auto" to autodetect optimal number of threads.
```

Note that since it's monerod actually mining, you can then exit monero-wallet-cli and monerod will continue mining. monerod commands work as well, so `stop_mining` in monerod will then stop background mining, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure out the actual command line:
`monerod --start-mining $wallet --mining-threads $threads --bg-mining-enable --bg-mining-ignore-battery`